# Weak Limit of Measures Mutually Singular wrt Lebesgue Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm stuck on the following qual problem:

Let $\{h_{n}\}$ be a sequence of positive continuous functions on the unit cube $Q$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ satisfying the following conditions:

- $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}h_{n}(x)=0$ $m$-a.e. ($m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $Q$)
- $\int_{Q}h_{n}dx=1$ $\forall n$
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{Q}fh_{n}dx=\int_{Q}fd\mu$ for every continuous function $f$ on $Q$.

Prove that $\mu\perp m$ or give a counterexample.

My intuition suggests to me that $\mu\perp m$ since $h_{n}\rightarrow 0$ a.e. and therefore must become very large on sets of small Lebesgue measure; however, I'm struggling to prove my guess. My thought was to write the $\int_{Q}fd\mu=\int_{Q}fh dx+\int_{Q}fd\nu$, where $hdx+\nu=\mu$ is the Lebesgue decomposition of $\mu$ and then show that $h=0$ $m$-a.e, or equivalently $\int_{Q}fhdx=0$ for every continuous $f$. But I have been unable to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to see how to give a hint without giving away at least whether it's a theorem or counterexample... Heh, I'll give one hint for each - one hint doesn't help. If you want to show $\mu\perp m$ Egoroff's theorem might be useful. If you want to construct a counterexample you might use this fact: If $h_n$ vanishes on $Q\setminus E_n$ and $\sum m(E_n)<\infty$ then $h_n\to0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: David, thank you for your comment. I'm not following what you're saying: I can't prove a theorem and give a counterexample to it--obviously, you know this. Also, $h_{n}$ is positive on $Q$, so it can't vanish on a set $Q\setminus E_{n}$ and one of the hypotheses is that $h_{n}\rightarrow 0$ a.e.

Comment: You said you'd prefer a hint to a solution. Half the problem is deciding whether it's a theorem or a counterexample. If I gave you a hint how to prove the theorem that would be doing half the problem for you. Similarly if I gave a hint for constructing a counterexample. So I gave you one of each...

Comment: Typically "positive" in measure theory means "non-negative". If your $h_n$ are strictly positive that doesn't matter - if you had a counterexample $h_n$ except that $h_n\ge0$ you could easily convert that to a strictly positive counterexample; for example, let $g_n=(1-1/n)h_n+1/n$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I think the theorem is true; I thought I wrote that in my original post. Sorry, I'm not trying to be annoyingly restrictive.

Comment: I saw that you thought the theorem was true! Does it follow that you want me to tell you for sure whether it's true or not?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Sure, please.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Would you please help me out some more. I thought was getting somewhere with Egoroff's theorem, but I am not. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: There exists a sequence of measures $\mu_n$ with $\mu_n\perp m$ such that $\int f\,d\mu_n\to\int f\,dx$ for every continuous $f$. (Hint for that: Riemann integral...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Yes, but in the problem the measures $\mu_{n}=h_{n}dx$ are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here, so please go ahead and share a complete answer if you have one. Sorry for the run around.

Comment: I understand what the problem says. You said you wanted a hint. I've given you a bunch. This is obviously a homework problem. First figure out measures $\mu_n$ as in my last hint. Then find $h_n$ that in some sense approximates $\mu_n$.

Comment: Tell you what. Think about it for two days. Remind me on Wednesday and I'll hand you the solution if you haven't got it yet.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: It's a qual problem that I've been stuck on. Sorry if I annoyed you.

Comment: Next time please don't say you don't want a complete solution if that's what you actually want. See, coming up with a reasonable hint was _harder_ than coming up with the solution. (II don't mean just that hint + solution $>$ solution. I mean hint $>$ solution, hence hint + solution $\ge$ $2$solution...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I apologize. I wrote that statement with sincerity at the time, but I've been thinking for this problem for a while and my frustration got the best of me. Please accept my apology and thank you for your patience.

Comment: It's possible I was more irritated than was really warranted. Bothered yesterday by non-math problems, sorry. (Yes, much better today.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flaw in reasoning that $\mu$ must be singular because $h_n$ is very small except on a very small set is that very small set can be somewhat uniformly distributed (at the right resolution).

Counterexample in one dimension:

Define $$I_{n,j}=[j/n,(j+2^{-n})/n].$$  Let $\phi_{n,j}$ be a continuous function supported on $I_{n,j}$ with $\phi_{n,j}\ge0$ and $$\int\phi_{n,j}=1/n.$$ Set $$E_n=\bigcup_{j=0}^{n-1}I_{n,j}.$$Let $$h_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\phi_{n,j}.$$Then $h_n\ge0$, $\int h_n=1$, and $$\int fh_n\to\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$$for every $f\in C([0,1])$. (Hint: $f$ is uniformly continuous. The idea behind the example is that $\int fh_n$ is morally equivalent to a Riemann sum for $\int f$.)

Since $h_n=0$ on $[0,1]\setminus E_n$ and $\sum m(E_n)<\infty$ it follows that $h_n\to0$ almost everywhere.

If $h_n\ge0$ is not positive enough, let $g_n=(1-1/n)h_n+1/n$.

**Exercise:** Suppose $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $[0,1]$. Show that there exist $h_n\ge0$ such that $h_n\to0$ almost everywhere but $\int fh_n\to\int f\,d\mu$ for every $f\in C([0,1])$.

Comment: This doesn't quite work since the $h_{n}$ are specified to be continuous in the problem statement, but I think see how to modify your idea to obtain this.

Comment: I missed the bit about continuity, sorry.

Comment: Fixed.  Now click on the arrow and the accept thingie and then do the exercise...